# Regular Expression: Matching a string with a variable inside for Find/Replace - Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

So, I'm trying to do a Find and Replace in notepad++ with regular expressions, because I have a 'Find' string that can have any number of characters between 2 quotes.  Here is a sample of my data.

```
<myVar Variable="MY-VAR" Type="string"/>
<myOtherVar Variable="MYOTHERVAR" Type="int"/>
<finalVar Variable="FVAR" Type="string"/>
```

So, I want to match ' `Variable="[everything inside the quotes]" T`' and replace it with ' `field="" t`'.

I don't want to save what's in the quotes.  The ultimate goal is to have lines that looks like this:

```
<myVar field="" type="string"/>
<myOtherVar field="" type="int"/>
<finalVar field="" type="string"/>
```

I think this has been my best attempt so far in the Find box, but ya'll can tell me if not. XD

```
/' variable="(\w+)" t'/
```

Thanks all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know the notepad++ regex syntax, but following idea should work:

try to replace

```
Variable="[^"]*"\s+T
```

with

```
field="" t
```

**EDIT**

I don't have windows machine, just installed notepad++ in a virtual box, and did a small test :)

the result looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Yours works fine in RegExr but not in Notepad++; Notepad++ does not support all RegEx Expressions. I am far by beeing an Expert on the subject though.

Comment: @leosok  I can say, I have experience with notepad++ now! see Edit. I didn't change my regex, just copy and paste.

Comment: You are right. This is what I tested your RegEx with: 
`<myVar field="" Type="string"/>
<myOtherVar field="" Type="int"/>
<finalVar field="" Type="string"/>`
On the original data it works fine. My apologies.

Comment: ok...maybe you didn't copy the `T`. anyway... the animation in my answer explains everything.

Comment: Thank you so much!  :D  Works like a charm, my fingers thank you for saving the C&Ping!

Answer (score 2):

With Notepad++ your RegEx will be:

```
Variable=".*"
```

Don't forget the last SPACE it's important. Replace it with

```
field=""
```

also containing a space as last character.

Greets

Comment: if this is really the **regex** syntax of notepad++, I would say.... strange.. what does the first `*` mean?

Comment: You are right. The first * is useless. It does not harm though.

Comment: what if `Variable=""` case? I meant, if the `*` still there.

Comment: this comment should go under my answer... :D

Comment: `*.*` did work, also for the `Variable=""` case because `*` "Matches 0 or more of the preceeding token. This is a greedy match, and will match as many characters as possible before satisfying the next token."

Comment: Thank you so much!  :D  If I could have 2 answers, I would mark yours too (because it works), but he actually also covered the last bit (replacing the T in Type to type).  A minor difference, I realize.  I upvoted you though, and thank you!

Comment: .* matches everything that is inside a certain pattern: very good!